# How can I get multiple messages scraped?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** multiple WhatsApp messages from the same date by the following code. However, this only gives the first message of that date (**4/21/2022**) **For instance:**

***Required output** should be:*

Hey there (message 1)

How are you? (message 2)

WBU? (message 3)

***Resulting output** is*

Hey there (message 1)

Hey there (message 1)

Hey there (message 1)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

day = input("Enter date: ")
month = input("Enter month: ")
year = input("Enter year: ")
date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, '_1vjYt'), 'WhatsApp Web'
    )
)


listContact = []
with open('cont.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        listContact.append(line)

for contact in listContact:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    hotel = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@title="{}"]'.format(contact))
    hotel.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    while (driver.find_element(
           By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-pre-plain-text*="{}"]'.format(date))):
        messages = driver.find_element(
           By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-pre-plain-text*="{}"]'.format(date))
           print(messages.text)
```

The **HTML coding** is following:

```
<div class="_2jGOb copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[2:39 PM, 5/1/2022] Joseph: ">
    <div class="_1Gy50">
        <span dir="ltr" class="i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
            <span>
                Hey, there
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="_2jGOb copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[2:40 PM, 5/1/2022] Joseph: ">
    <div class="_1Gy50">
        <span dir="ltr" class="i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
            <span>
                How are you?
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="_2jGOb copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[2:39 PM, 5/1/2022] Joseph: ">
    <div class="_1Gy50">
        <span dir="ltr" class="i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text">
            <span>
                WBU?
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the last while() cycle would be better rewritten as

```
elements = driver.find_element(
           By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-pre-plain-text*="{}"]'.format(date))
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

You are getting the same output because the body of while cycle starts new independent iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` (without `s` at the end) is finding always only first element on page - and it doesn't matter how many times you use it.

you have to use `find_elements` (with `s` at the end) to get all elements - and later use `for`-loop

```
css = 'div[data-pre-plain-text*="{}"]'.format(date)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```